# Angular2 unit test Click() with keypress

Tags: unit-testing, sorting, angular, click, keyboard-events

I am trying to test a sorting function for a table. The table enables sorting on a primaray and secondary value. The secondary sorting value is set by holding down the shift key.

Code for setting the sort order:

```
private sortClick(event: any, column: DataGridColumn): void {
    if (!column.sortable) {
        return;
    }

    if (event.shiftKey) { // When the shift key is pressed, secondary sorting is being set.
        if (column.headerText === this.primarySorting.headerText) {
            return;
        }
        this.secondarySortingColumn.setSortingProperty(column.headerText, column.name);
    } else {
        this.primarySorting.setSortingProperty(column.headerText, column.name);
        this.secondarySortingColumn.clear();
    }

    this.sortData(this);
}
```

Now I'm writing the unit testst for the function.
The primary sorting is done using the following:

```
    let firstColumn: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = <NodeListOf<HTMLElement>>compiled.querySelectorAll("#header0");
    firstColumn.item(0).click();
```

How can I call the `.click()` function with `shift key pressed` in the `unit test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dispaatchEvent` method to invoke the click event and supply other event information as follows:

```js
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'shiftKey': true
});

let firstColumn: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = <NodeListOf<HTMLElement>>compiled.querySelectorAll("#header0");
firstColumn.item(0).dispatchEvent(event);
```

Note the `shiftKey` member is set to true in the `mouseEventInit` dictionary parameter to the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Constructor) constructor which allows us to specify that the shiftKey is pressed.